# JS How can i make FormData with Image in object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have a Object kinda like :

```
{
  Description:"Some Description",
  MainImage:File  //Image File,
  Name:"Test Name",
  Details:[ 
            {Description:"Detail Description 1",Image:File //Image File Again  },
            {Description:"Detail Description 2",Image:File //Image File Again  }, 
        ] 
}
```

I can put single image files to formdata like

```
FormData.append("MainImage",obj.MainImage)
```

But for objects how can i make formdata for images?
when i make `FormData.append("Details[]",obj.Details[0])` it doesnt work. What should i do for make it formData element ? Thanks for responses!

Comment: `obj.Details[0]` is a plain object. Not an image file. If you want the image file in it, then you have to use the property name!!

Comment: @Quentin thats the problem i have actually. I want file in object. But i dont know how can i make it can you give me one simple example for how can i make it please ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/MSgnbZN

Comment: @Quentin I know its property name. I mean i want to send a object with a file. I want send description and image together in 1 object. How can i append it thats what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
let obj = {
  Description:"Some Description",
  MainImage:File  //Image File,
  Name:"Test Name",
  Details:[ 
            {Description:"Detail Description 1",Image:File},
            {Description:"Detail Description 2",Image:File}, 
          ] 
}
FormData.append("MainImage", JSON.stringify(obj))
```